# OpenApi generator doesn't allow multiple schema in content

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-codegen, openapi-generator

I've an OpenAPI contract like this:

```
openapi: 3.0.1
info:
  title: Internal API
  version: ''
tags:
  - name: Calendar
    description: Api for Calendar resource
paths:
  '/api/v1/appointments/{id}':
    get:
      tags:
        - Calendar
      summary: Get the given appointment
      description: Get the given appointment
      operationId: findById
      parameters:
        - name: id
          in: path
          description: The appointment Id
          required: true
          schema:
            type: integer
            format: int64
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Successful operation
          content:
            application/vnd.widget+json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/AppointmentWidgetDto'
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Appointment'
      
components:
  schemas:
    AppointmentWidgetDto:
      required:
        - contactEmail
        - contactName
        - contactPhone
        - endDate
        - startDate
        - store
        - title
      type: object
      properties:
        store:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/Store'
        title:
          maxLength: 255
          minLength: 0
          type: string
        description:
          maxLength: 1024
          minLength: 0
          type: string
        type:
          maxLength: 50
          minLength: 0
          type: string
        icon:
          maxLength: 50
          minLength: 0
          type: string
        startDate:
          type: string
          format: date-time
        endDate:
          type: string
          format: date-time
        contact:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/Contact'
        contactName:
          type: string
        contactEmail:
          type: string
        contactPhone:
          type: string
    AuditUser:
      type: object
      properties:
        sid:
          type: string
        fullName:
          type: string
    Contact:
      required:
        - billingCountry
        - personType
        - preset
        - publicAdministration
        - shippingCountry
        - status
        - type
      type: object
      properties:
        id:
          type: integer
          format: int64
        sid:
          type: string
        createdBy:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/AuditUser'
        createdDate:
          type: string
          format: date-time
        lastModifiedDate:
          type: string
          format: date-time
        lastModifiedBy:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/AuditUser'
        version:
          type: integer
          format: int64
        userInputTime:
          type: integer
          format: int64
        type:
          type: string
          enum:
            - CUSTOMER
            - SUPPLIER
            - CUSTOMER_SUPPLIER
            - SUBCONTRACTOR
        personType:
          type: string
          enum:
            - NATURAL_PERSON
            - LEGAL_PERSON
        extCode:
          maxLength: 50
          minLength: 0
          type: string
        lotteryCode:
          maxLength: 8
          minLength: 0
          type: string
        firstName:
          type: string
        lastName:
          type: string
        companyName:
          type: string
        fullName:
          type: string
          readOnly: true
        gender:
          type: string
          enum:
            - MALE
            - FEMALE
            - OTHER
        birthDate:
          type: string
          format: date
        birthCity:
          type: string
        job:
          maxLength: 100
          minLength: 0
          type: string
        billingAddress:
          type: string
        billingZipCode:
          type: string
        billingCity:
          type: string
        billingDistrict:
          type: string
        billingCountry:
          maxLength: 2
          minLength: 2
          type: string
        shippingAddress:
          type: string
        shippingZipCode:
          type: string
        shippingCity:
          type: string
        shippingDistrict:
          type: string
        shippingCountry:
          maxLength: 2
          minLength: 2
          type: string
        taxCode:
          type: string
        vatNumber:
          type: string
        landlinePhone:
          type: string
        mobilePhone:
          type: string
        fax:
          type: string
        email:
          type: string
        certifiedEmail:
          type: string
        workingDistance:
          type: string
          enum:
            - FAR_NEAR
            - INTERMEDIATE_NEAR
            - NEAR
            - FAR_INTERMEDIATE
        bankName:
          type: string
        iban:
          type: string
        swift:
          type: string
        publicAdministration:
          type: boolean
        sdiAccountId:
          type: string
        store:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/Store'
        preset:
          type: boolean
        avatar:
          type: boolean
        status:
          type: string
          enum:
            - ACTIVE
            - DECEASED
        completenessScore:
          type: number
          readOnly: true
        tags:
          type: string
        age:
          type: integer
          format: int32
    Store:
      required:
        - address
        - city
        - code
        - country
        - district
        - name
        - whatsAppEnabled
        - zipCode
      type: object
      properties:
        id:
          type: integer
          format: int64
        sid:
          type: string
        createdBy:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/AuditUser'
        createdDate:
          type: string
          format: date-time
        lastModifiedDate:
          type: string
          format: date-time
        lastModifiedBy:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/AuditUser'
        version:
          type: integer
          format: int64
        userInputTime:
          type: integer
          format: int64
        name:
          type: string
        code:
          type: string
        extCode:
          maxLength: 50
          minLength: 0
          type: string
        address:
          type: string
        zipCode:
          type: string
        city:
          type: string
        district:
          type: string
        country:
          maxLength: 2
          minLength: 2
          type: string
        landlinePhone:
          type: string
        mobilePhone:
          type: string
        whatsAppEnabled:
          type: boolean
        fax:
          type: string
        email:
          type: string
        certifiedEmail:
          type: string
        openingHours:
          maxLength: 1024
          minLength: 0
          type: string
        contactMinScore:
          maximum: 10
          minimum: 0
          type: number
    Agent:
      required:
        - country
        - email
        - firstName
        - gender
        - language
        - lastName
        - user
        - verified
      type: object
      properties:
        id:
          type: integer
          format: int64
        sid:
          type: string
        createdBy:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/AuditUser'
        createdDate:
          type: string
          format: date-time
        lastModifiedDate:
          type: string
          format: date-time
        lastModifiedBy:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/AuditUser'
        version:
          type: integer
          format: int64
        userInputTime:
          type: integer
          format: int64
        user:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/User'
        firstName:
          type: string
        lastName:
          type: string
        gender:
          type: string
          enum:
            - MALE
            - FEMALE
            - OTHER
        color:
          maxLength: 30
          minLength: 0
          type: string
        employeeId:
          type: string
        address:
          type: string
        zipCode:
          type: string
        city:
          type: string
        district:
          type: string
        country:
          maxLength: 2
          minLength: 2
          type: string
        birthDate:
          type: string
          format: date
        taxCode:
          type: string
        vatNumber:
          type: string
        landlinePhone:
          type: string
        mobilePhone:
          type: string
        email:
          type: string
        verified:
          type: boolean
          readOnly: true
        language:
          maxLength: 2
          minLength: 2
          type: string
        iban:
          type: string
        swift:
          type: string
        stores:
          uniqueItems: true
          type: array
          items:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/Store'
        avatar:
          type: boolean
          readOnly: true
        tourCompleted:
          type: boolean
          readOnly: true
        enabled:
          type: boolean
          writeOnly: true
        password:
          type: string
          writeOnly: true
        lastPasswordUpdate:
          type: string
          format: date-time
        username:
          type: string
        roles:
          uniqueItems: true
          type: array
          items:
            type: string
            enum:
              - ROLE_ADMIN
        userSid:
          type: string
    Appointment:
      required:
        - allDay
        - endDate
        - startDate
        - status
        - store
        - title
      type: object
      properties:
        id:
          type: integer
          format: int64
        sid:
          type: string
        createdBy:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/AuditUser'
        createdDate:
          type: string
          format: date-time
        lastModifiedDate:
          type: string
          format: date-time
        lastModifiedBy:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/AuditUser'
        version:
          type: integer
          format: int64
        userInputTime:
          type: integer
          format: int64
        store:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/Store'
        title:
          maxLength: 255
          minLength: 0
          type: string
        description:
          maxLength: 1024
          minLength: 0
          type: string
        color:
          maxLength: 30
          minLength: 0
          type: string
        type:
          maxLength: 50
          minLength: 0
          type: string
        icon:
          maxLength: 50
          minLength: 0
          type: string
        location:
          maxLength: 255
          minLength: 0
          type: string
        startDate:
          type: string
          format: date-time
        endDate:
          type: string
          format: date-time
        allDay:
          type: boolean
        contact:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/Contact'
        contactName:
          type: string
        contactEmail:
          type: string
        contactPhone:
          type: string
        agent:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/Agent'
        agentName:
          type: string
        status:
          type: string
          readOnly: true
          enum:
            - TO_APPROVE
            - VALID
            - CANCELED
            - DECLINED
    GrantedAuthority:
      type: object
      properties:
        authority:
          type: string
    User:
      required:
        - enabled
        - fullName
        - roles
        - username
      type: object
      properties:
        id:
          type: integer
          format: int64
        sid:
          type: string
        createdBy:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/AuditUser'
        createdDate:
          type: string
          format: date-time
        lastModifiedDate:
          type: string
          format: date-time
        lastModifiedBy:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/AuditUser'
        version:
          type: integer
          format: int64
        userInputTime:
          type: integer
          format: int64
        fullName:
          type: string
        username:
          maxLength: 255
          minLength: 3
          type: string
        enabled:
          type: boolean
          readOnly: true
        roles:
          maxItems: 2147483647
          minItems: 1
          uniqueItems: true
          type: array
          items:
            type: string
            enum:
              - ROLE_ADMIN
        accountNonExpired:
          type: boolean
        credentialsNonExpired:
          type: boolean
        authorities:
          type: array
          items:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/GrantedAuthority'
        accountNonLocked:
          type: boolean
```

I want my endpoint `/api/v1/appointments/{id}` return 2 different representations of my resource Appointment: the full resource and a light one (with less data).
I thought using content's schema is the right thing to do, so the client can easily decide what it wants.

I tried to generate some clients from this contract using `Swagger editor` and `OpenApi generator` but I see these Warning:

```
[WARNING] Multiple schemas found in the OAS 'content' section, returning only the first one (application/vnd.widget+json)
```

and my client, as expected from that message, has only one method that returns only 1 representation of the resource.

I found this bug https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/144, but at the same time I think this is a very basic concept of HTTP/REST and I'm bit surpriced it doesn't work.
Indeed I'm questioning myself doing something wrong. Is there a way to describe a single endpoint returning different representations of the same resouce (OpenApi contract) generating the client with both methods needed to get the already mentioned resource's representations?

Comment: If you like to generate code for spring boot (or micronaut)  you could try https://docs.openapiprocessor.io. It will generate multiple methods in this case. Here is an example (it is a bit slow on the first run) https://playground.openapiprocessor.io/input?sample=response-content-multiple&format=spring

Comment: @MartinHauner thanks. Unfortunately I need to generate the Angular client and it seems not supported.